# Offset an image by half?

Tags: html, css

I have a gold box, I want the image inside the gold box to be centered half off the gold box so that the center point of the image is sitting at the top of the gold box.

Is like a product box with the image sat at the top.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v992pqmw/)

I've tried:

```
margin-top: -50%;
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that?

https://jsfiddle.net/v992pqmw/

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now there is a gap between the image and the content, how can I tighten that up?